# C# resizing image

Tags: c#, itext, image-resizing

I'm working with a project that need to realtime resizing DatamatrixCode image(using ZXing)and show on PictureBox(Visual Studio 2019), I'm originally using C# System.Drawing(because need to draw something on it), but it's got very blurred if I zoom in/out, I've tried tranfer to pdf(using PdfiumViewer/iText7 library to draw and save) and transfer back to stream or byte[], it's what i want but it UI controller is very inconvenient in realtime showing/editing on winform.

I want image's resolution be like when scaling PDF type picture, but in bitmap/image type way, How can i achieve that?
I also tried transfer to svg, but after google it seems there are completely two type of things.

Comment: How are you scaling the image? You should typically scale the image during drawing, to let the GPU do most of the work. Some blurring is unavoidable when zooming in, but may also be caused by incorrect usage. But without seeing what you have done, or even what UI framework you are using, there is little we can do to help.

Comment: Look at [.NET Core Image Processing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/). Choose the best library.